# Undefined method `set_facebook_session' exception thrown when trying to use the Facebooker wrapper for Rails and Facebook Connect API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker

I followed all the steps given in [this](http://madebymany.co.uk/tutorial-for-restful_authentication-on-rails-with-facebook-connect-in-15-minutes-00523) blog. When i am trying to point my browser to the "/login" I get the following exception

```
undefined method `set_facebook_session' for #<SessionsController:0x15b0618>
```

I tried searching in lot of forums but couldn't find the solution. Even if i comment out the use of set_facebook_session i get the following exception

```
undefined method `fb_login_button' for #<ActionView::Base:0x2d2c6ac>
```

This shows that the Facebooker library is not getting included. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebooker is available as a gem now, so you shouldn't use the plugin.

```
gem install facebooker
```

Then in your routes.rb file you'll want to include the facebooker gem:

```
config.gem "facebooker"
```